# How to set an ImageButton in TextBox

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox, imagebutton

I have this multiline textbox. I want to add an ImageButton to the top left of the textbox.

I saw a few methods but none of them seemed to be too much of a help.

**What is the best solution to add an ImageButton to that Multiline textbox?**

Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" Width="98%" Height="300px" style="overflow:auto" BorderStyle="Outset" BorderWidth="2px"
            runat="server" Visible="false" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="true" ></asp:TextBox>
</p>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
protected void SetTextBox(int levelID)
{
    switch (levelID)
    {
        case 1: // = not started yet
            txtDescription.CssClass = "textBoxWhite";                
            break;
        case 2: //= in proccess
            txtDescription.CssClass = "textBoxBlue";
            break;
        case 3: //= completed
            txtDescription.CssClass = "textBoxRed";
            break;
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.textBoxRed 
 { 

       background: rgba(255, 181, 181, 0.5);
 }

 .textBoxBlue 
 { 
      background: rgba(181, 181, 255, 0.5);
 }

 .textBoxWhite
 {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 }
```

**EXAMPLE: See the "Image in textBox**
[Image in textbox](http://www.cssportal.com/form-elements/text-box.htm)

[image: This is how it needs to look like:]

Comment: You want to display an ImageButton inside the TextBox instead of above/under it?

Comment: yes,I believe he is saying that but I think he actually needs to put above it.

Comment: I've added an example above to clarify how it needs to look like.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**if you want to have an image inside your textarea** you could do something like this:

*HTML*

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" CssClass="nice-input" ...></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.nice-input
{
    background:#FFFFFF url('http://www.cssportal.com/form-elements/images/search.png') no-repeat 4px 4px;
    padding:25px 4px 4px 4px;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    width:98%;
    height:300px;
}​
```

**If you need to have a submit image button** you could do something like this

*HTML*

```
<div>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ClickMeButton" CssClass="nice-button" ...></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" CssClass="nice-input" ...></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.nice-input
{
    padding:25px 4px 4px 4px;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    width:98%;
    height:300px;
}

.nice-button
{
    background:#FFFFFF url('http://www.cssportal.com/form-elements/images/search.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
    position:relative;
    top:24px;
    left:4px;
}​
```

**Note** The second solution is very hackish. if you could use jQuery to perform the post instead of your asp:ImageButton it could be much nicer.

Comment: Gabriel, maybe I didn't quiet explain myself. I have a textbox, and I want to put an imagebutton inside the border of that textbox. I gave an example with an image just to explain how I want that to look like.
Thank you and sorry for missleading you :)

Comment: I also added a picture for clarification (which I didnt manage to upload from my work place few hours ago for some reason)

Comment: It's what my answer is doing. I created a jsFiddle to demonstrate it: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielweyer/HGvbD/ I assumed you don't want the image to be clickable or used as a button. If you want to use it as a button I'll have to revert to my first answer

Comment: If it is not too much to ask, please do :)

Comment: Done, depending of your existing CSS classes you might have to play around a bit. Again if you can move to ASP.NET MVC 4, jQuery... do so. ASP.NET Pages takes the fun away of web dev.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel, it works. I will take your advice into consideration but in the meanwhile in order to show some results I will make it this "hackish" way.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help :)